# rabbitmq / logstash lost message

Tags: rabbitmq, logstash, pika

I have a rabbitmq which stores message successfully but my logstash reading the queue ignore most of my messages.

***RabbitMQ is OK***, I have a small python script to display all messages

```
import pika
i=0
def on_message(channel, method_frame, header_frame, body):
    global i
    print i
    print("Message body", body)
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)
    i+=1

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('***', '***')
parameters =  pika.ConnectionParameters('***',5672,'logstash', credentials=credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange="logstash", exchange_type="topic", passive=False, durable=True, auto_delete=False)
channel.queue_declare(queue="hbbtv", auto_delete=False, durable=True)
channel.queue_bind(queue="hbbtv", exchange="logstash", routing_key="hbbtv")
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

channel.basic_consume(on_message, 'hbbtv')

try:
    channel.start_consuming()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    channel.stop_consuming()

connection.close()
```

I can see all my messages

> 12 ('Message body', '{"message":"212.95.70.118 - -
>   [25/Feb/2016:11:19:53 +0100] \"GET
>   /services/web/index.php/OPA/categories/ARTEPLUS7/fr HTTP/1.1\" 200
>   348
>   \"[http://www.arte.tv/hbbtvv2/notv/cehtml/index.cehtml?lang=de_DE&page=PLUS7&tv=false\](http://www.arte.tv/hbbtvv2/notv/cehtml/index.cehtml?lang=de_DE&page=PLUS7&tv=false%5C)"
>   \"Opera/9.80 (Linux armv7l;  HbbTV/1.1.1 (; Philips; ; ; PhilipsTV; )
>   CE-HTML/1.0 NETTV/4.3.1 PhilipsTV/2.1.1 Firmware/003.015.000.001
>   (PhilipsTV, 2.1.1,) en) Presto/2.12.362 Version/12.11 \"
>   hbbtvdyn.arte.tv","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-02-25T10:19:53.000Z","path":"/data/logs/access","host":"arte-hbbtvdyn-web1.sdv.fr","type":"apache-access","application":"hbbtv","clientip":"212.95.70.118","ident":"-","auth":"-","timestamp":"25/Feb/2016:11:19:53 +0100","verb":"GET","request":"/services/web/index.php/OPA/categories/ARTEPLUS7/fr","httpversion":"1.1","response":"200","bytes":"348","referrer":"\"[http://www.arte.tv/hbbtvv2/notv/cehtml/index.cehtml?lang=de_DE&page=PLUS7&tv=false\](http://www.arte.tv/hbbtvv2/notv/cehtml/index.cehtml?lang=de_DE&page=PLUS7&tv=false%5C)"","agent":"\"Opera/9.80
>   (Linux armv7l;  HbbTV/1.1.1 (; Philips; ; ; PhilipsTV; ) CE-HTML/1.0
>   NETTV/4.3.1 PhilipsTV/2.1.1 Firmware/003.015.000.001 (PhilipsTV,
>   2.1.1,) en) Presto/2.12.362 Version/12.11 \"","targethost":"hbbtvdyn.arte.tv","geoip":{"ip":"212.95.70.118","country_code2":"FR","country_code3":"FRA","country_name":"France","continent_code":"EU","region_name":"C1","city_name":"Strasbourg","latitude":48.60040000000001,"longitude":7.787399999999991,"timezone":"Europe/Paris","real_region_name":"Alsace","location":[7.787399999999991,48.60040000000001]}}')
>   13 ('Message body', '{"message":"212.95.70.118 - -
>   [25/Feb/2016:11:19:53 +0100] \"GET
>   /services/web/index.php/OPA/videos/highlights/6/ARTEPLUS7/de/GE
>   HTTP/1.1\" 500 4519
>   \"[http://www.arte.tv/hbbtvv2/notv/cehtml/index.cehtml?lang=de_DE&page=PLUS7&tv=false\](http://www.arte.tv/hbbtvv2/notv/cehtml/index.cehtml?lang=de_DE&page=PLUS7&tv=false%5C)"
>   \"Opera/9.80 (Linux armv7l;  HbbTV/1.1.1 (; Philips; ; ; PhilipsTV; )
>   CE-HTML/1.0 NETTV/4.3.1 PhilipsTV/2.1.1 Firmware/003.015.000.001
>   (PhilipsTV, 2.1.1,) en) Presto/2.12.362 Version/12.11 \"
>   hbbtvdyn.arte.tv","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-02-25T10:19:53.000Z","path":"/data/logs/access","host":"arte-hbbtvdyn-web1.sdv.fr","type":"apache-access","application":"hbbtv","clientip":"212.95.70.118","ident":"-","auth":"-","timestamp":"25/Feb/2016:11:19:53 +0100","verb":"GET","request":"/services/web/index.php/OPA/videos/highlights/6/ARTEPLUS7/de/GE","httpversion":"1.1","response":"500","bytes":"4519","referrer":"\"[http://www.arte.tv/hbbtvv2/notv/cehtml/index.cehtml?lang=de_DE&page=PLUS7&tv=false\](http://www.arte.tv/hbbtvv2/notv/cehtml/index.cehtml?lang=de_DE&page=PLUS7&tv=false%5C)"","agent":"\"Opera/9.80
>   (Linux armv7l;  HbbTV/1.1.1 (; Philips; ; ; PhilipsTV; ) CE-HTML/1.0
>   NETTV/4.3.1 PhilipsTV/2.1.1 Firmware/003.015.000.001 (PhilipsTV,
>   2.1.1,) en) Presto/2.12.362 Version/12.11 \"","targethost":"hbbtvdyn.arte.tv","geoip":{"ip":"212.95.70.118","country_code2":"FR","country_code3":"FRA","country_name":"France","continent_code":"EU","region_name":"C1","city_name":"Strasbourg","latitude":48.60040000000001,"longitude":7.787399999999991,"timezone":"Europe/Paris","real_region_name":"Alsace","location":[7.787399999999991,48.60040000000001]}}')
>   14 ('Message body', '{"message":"212.95.70.119 - -
>   [25/Feb/2016:11:19:53 +0100] \"GET
>   /OPA/getOPAData.php?url=videoStreams%3Flanguage%3Dfr%26protocol%3DHTTP%26mediaType%3Dmp4%26quality%3DEQ%2CSQ%2CHQ%26profileAmm%3D%24nin%3AAMM-YTFR-HAB%2CAMM-YTFR%2CAMM-DT%26kind%3DSHOW%26availableScreens%3Dtv%26fields%3DprogramId%2Curl%2Cquality%2CaudioSlot%2CaudioCode%2CaudioLabel%2CaudioShortLabel%2Cchannel%26programId%3D048353-033-A%26platform%3DARTEPLUS7&filename=PLUS7_stream_048353-033-A_fr_FR.json
>   HTTP/1.1\" 200 5508 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Tizen 2.3;
>   SmartHub; SMART-TV; SmartTV; U; Maple2012) AppleWebKit/538.1+ (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) TV Safari/538.1+ \"
>   hbbtvdyn.arte.tv","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-02-25T10:19:53.000Z","path":"/data/logs/access","host":"arte-hbbtvdyn-web1.sdv.fr","type":"apache-access","application":"hbbtv","clientip":"212.95.70.119","ident":"-","auth":"-","timestamp":"25/Feb/2016:11:19:53 +0100","verb":"GET","request":"/OPA/getOPAData.php?url=videoStreams%3Flanguage%3Dfr%26protocol%3DHTTP%26mediaType%3Dmp4%26quality%3DEQ%2CSQ%2CHQ%26profileAmm%3D%24nin%3AAMM-YTFR-HAB%2CAMM-YTFR%2CAMM-DT%26kind%3DSHOW%26availableScreens%3Dtv%26fields%3DprogramId%2Curl%2Cquality%2CaudioSlot%2CaudioCode%2CaudioLabel%2CaudioShortLabel%2Cchannel%26programId%3D048353-033-A%26platform%3DARTEPLUS7&filename=PLUS7_stream_048353-033-A_fr_FR.json","httpversion":"1.1","response":"200","bytes":"5508","referrer":"\"-\"","agent":"\"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Linux; Tizen 2.3; SmartHub; SMART-TV; SmartTV; U; Maple2012)
>   AppleWebKit/538.1+ (KHTML, like Gecko) TV Safari/538.1+
>   \"","targethost":"hbbtvdyn.arte.tv","geoip":{"ip":"212.95.70.119","country_code2":"FR","country_code3":"FRA","country_name":"France","continent_code":"EU","region_name":"C1","city_name":"Strasbourg","latitude":48.60040000000001,"longitude":7.787399999999991,"timezone":"Europe/Paris","real_region_name":"Alsace","location":[7.787399999999991,48.60040000000001]}}')

with the good rate message (several per seconds) and I have absolutely not grok parse failure.

So the issue happen while logstash read message. Problems are

- a lot of message missing
- all message have _grokparsefailure even if
  it's complete

[image: message in elasticsearch]

The input part of logstash is

```
rabbitmq {
    host=>"arte-elasticlog.sdv.fr"
    user=>"***"
    password=>"***"
    queue=>"hbbtv"
    vhost=>"logstash"
    port=>5672
    auto_delete=>false
    durable=>true
    type => "rabbit_hbbtv"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to my logstash filter,
I had two apache access but with different pattern so when logstash tried to parsee a message, sometimes he had the good pattern --> in ES and sometimes not --> no message.

Now, for all my different log, I add (add-field)

```
application-->"my application name"
```

in my input and all my grok filter depends on the application.

All is good now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

_grokparsefailure indicates that it is unable to parse the message. meaning the message successfully read from the queue, but your grok expression has problem or could not be applied on your message content.

One more thing is the default codec of the rabbitmq input is "json", if your rabbitmq message content is not json, you should set the codec of your input to for instance:

codec => plain {}

Comment: Thanks @teddy-ma, but the rabbit message is valid json, tested with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: What's your grok expression?